# R studio (markdown) error: Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name and Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object not found

Tags: r, syntax-error

I have read the questions/answers on this site, bit nothing I have tried has worked (including updating packages, running specific lines using the "play button", calling in the data again, and clearing global environment on R Studio). I am using am excel dataset (xls), and have tried running simple regression code, along with MLM code and I cannot get anything to work, except summary code. I have tried many different lines of code with different variables, but here is one example:

```
m1<- lmer(latency~Condition +(Condition|subject), data=stroop9_30_19)

lm(correct~Conditon)
```

The errors switch back and forth between:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'correct' not found AND

Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

The variables are in the dataset because the summary code includes those variables. Any ideas?

Comment: In your `lm` call the `data` argument is missing

Comment: Doesn't work with data statement either.

Comment: can you add in your question the result of `dput(head(stroop9_30_19))`?  Without your dataframe it is difficult to answer